# Prevent files from duplicating when automatically moving them into folders

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

The idea is that I am going to drop a bunch of files into the SharePoint folder, in this case I dropped two

[image: overhead_press2_0-1621123367368.jpeg]

Then the flow will automatically generate a bunch of folders based on the beginning of the file names and place them into the corresponding folders.

[image]

Below are the two folders that are created from dropping the two files. The issue I am experiencing is that all the files are being duplicated in each of the folders when there should only be one file in each of the folders that has the matching name:

[image: overhead_press2_2-1621123367418.png]

[image: overhead_press2_3-1621123367497.png]

What is wrong with my flow below and how can I change it so that only the correct file shows in each of the folders? (Ex. file "J0000-1002_.......PDF" only shows in folder "J0000-1002". Thanks in advance!

[image: overhead_press2_4-1621123367421.png]

[image: overhead_press2_5-1621123367509.png]

[image: overhead_press2_6-1621123367422.png]

Let me know if you need clarification on the flow, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'Get Files (properties only)' action, not 'Get file properties' action (single item) and the apply to each loop will do it for every file. You need to switch to Get single File and get rid of apply to each step.